# Do questions on the Game Center belong on here or Gaming.SE?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is no tag for the iOS Game Center.

Should any questions on it be asked here, or on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ or elsewhere?

Or should cross-posting be allowed in this instance?

Answer (score 3):

Game Center would be on-topic here since it is Apple software.

However, if you're asking about programming or developing for/with Game Center, that would be off-topic since this site is not about development. That kind of a question should go on Stack Overflow.

**If you've got a question about Game Center that doesn't involve development/programming, go ahead and ask it here. I can easily make you a `[game-center]` tag.**

Comment: Plus, there's also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is not to do with development, but this is quite in-depth for Game Center - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19774/possible-to-force-a-sync-of-game-center-achievements-already-gained, it might be solved by individual apps, so cross-posting might be valid?